# SpringMVC change JSP with post

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm trying to update the user's current JSP on a post request. I am using @Controller annotation right now (I've also tried RestController)

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = { "postHome" })
    public ModelAndView postHome(@RequestBody String body, ModelAndView model) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
        String customerName = jsonObject.getString("customerName");

        model.setViewName("feasibility");
        model.addObject("customerName", customerName);

        return model;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
function postCustomer() {
                var custName = {
                    "customerName": document.getElementById("customerName").value
                };

                fetch(sendURL, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(custName)
                });
            }
```

It's posting to the server just fine (I've printed out the `body`), but nothing happens after that. No errors or anything. The JSP I am trying to update the client with is `feasibility.jsp`. I tried something earlier and it was trying to force my client to run a GET on `localhost:8080/feasibility?customerName=Name` but that's not what I was trying to do.

In the past I was able to just return "feasibility" as a String, but that doesn't work with this project (could be the versions I was using before).

Thanks!

Comment: any reason you are using JavaScript, you can directly use the jsp to do that

Comment: I think this is expected behavior if you are using ajax request.

Comment: @Anil this is what I've been taught previously. if there's a better way to do it, I'm game. When I set verbose debugging in `application.properties`, it shows that it's forwarding to `feasibility.jsp` but the webpage doesn't actually update.